# Validity of RLGC model for QTEM transmission lines with numerically calculated characteristic impedance and propagation constant

Tags: rf, simulation, transmission-line

## My problem

In my understanding, any system that supports a QTEM mode can be represented by an RLGC transmission line model with negligible error. Indeed, when I perform a calculation in CST microwave studio of a simple CPW of silver metal on a GaAs substrate, the x and y component of the fields are about 3 orders of magnitude greater than the z component, making this a (for all practical purposes) a TEM mode. Therefore, using the transmission line theory with the values of the line impedance and propagation constant returned by the software I ought to be able to calculate the S parameters without the need to perform a full 3D FEM simulation. I can then use (Ref2):

$$
S_{11} = \frac{j(Z_c^2-Z_0^2)\sinh (\gamma l)}{2Z_cZ_0\cosh (\gamma l)+(Z_c^2+Z_0^2)\sinh(\gamma l)}
$$

$$
S_{12} = \frac{2Z_cZ_0}{2Z_cZ_0\cosh (\gamma l)+(Z_c^2+Z_0^2)\sinh(\gamma l)}
$$

[image]

Doing so, however, results in S11 and S12 values different from the ones resulting from an FEM simulation as you can see below. While the S12 values are rather similar, the reflection ones are not, by a lot.

[image]

## My question

It boils down to: **Is my approach valid?**. From Ref1 in chapter 3:

> The TEM wave is the principal wave that can exist on a transmission
> line

When reading further on the book, in chapter 4, they state that:

> When the propagating mode is nota TEM or quasi-TEM mode, there is no unique value for the characteristic impedance because it is not possible to define a unique value for the voltage as given by the line integral of the electric field between the ground plane and the microstrip.

This now begs the question: could the deviation of my results stem from a numerical artifact on the characteristic impedance calculation? Or is there something more fundamental that I am missing?

Ref1 - Collin, Robert E. 2001. Foundations for Microwave Engineering. 2. ed., [Nachdr.]. IEEE Press Series on Electromagnetic Wave Theory. New York, NY: IEEE Press.

Ref2 - Rizzi, Peter A. 1988. Microwave Engineering: Passive Circuits. Englewood Cliffs, N.J: Prentice Hall.

Comment: The values returned by the FEM may not be directly usable in RLGC. Treat RLGC as a generic parametric model, and fit its parameters to match FEM output in the frequency range of interest, say 5-45GHz I presume? See by how much the fit parameters differ from those from FEM. It may turn out that in your particular case S11 is somehow very sensitive to the parameter values. But it's suspicious a bit and looks more like a clerical error. You sure that there was no errata for the S11 source, and did you confirm it with a second source that independently derived it (vs. citing the same paper)?

Comment: The formulas can be derived starting from the ABCD matrix and then apply the transformation to an S matrix, and I have checked the calculations myself as I couldn't find a source for it. 

I don't understand what you mean when you say: "The values returned by the FEM may not be directly usable in RLGC.". Why not?